# std::map gives typeconversion error, but only when compiling for x86

Tags: c++, c++11, x86, stdmap

Using Visual Studio 2017, I have a section of code where I define a std::map that compiles fine in x64 but returns an error when compiled for x86.

The map in question keys on an enum and returns a struct with a descriptor string and some function pointers.

I went through my project settings and confirmed the only difference in my C++ compiler settings between the two is the architecture flag.  My best guess is it has something to do with the function pointers in each map entry, since I have other std::maps in this same file containing structs of strings and doubles/floats that all work fine.

The specific error thrown is C2440: *Can't convert from type1 to type2*, with the text *cannot convert from 'initializer list' to `std::map<int,PropertyMetaData, std::less<_Kty>, std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>`*

## EDIT:

I made the most compact example I could without any external dependencies.  I get no errors in x64 but I get the type conversion error when set to x86:

```
#include <map>

typedef double(*convertFunc)(int, int, double);
typedef int(*convertFuncD)(int, int, double*,double*,int);

extern "C" {
    __declspec(dllexport) double __stdcall Pressure(
        int inUnits,
        int outUnits,
        double inValue
    );

    __declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall PressureD(
        int inUnits,
        int outUnits,
        double* inValue,
        double* outValue,
        int n
    );
}

//Metadata for each Property
struct PropertyMetaData {
    const char desc[20]; //Text description
    const convertFunc func; //double conversion function
    const convertFuncD funcArrayD; //array double conversion function
};

// Map containing all of the properties and their metadata
typedef std::map<int, PropertyMetaData> PropertiesMap;

const PropertiesMap conversions = {
    //Mapping The type of unit (mass, distance, etc.) to the appropriate function

    //Enumeration                   {desc[20],      func,        arrayfuncD,   arrayFuncF   }
    { 1,    {"Pressure",    Pressure,    PressureD}},
};
```

After some more experimenting, it seems to be caused by the __stdcall qualifier.  If that's removed, I have no issues with either architecture.

Comment: can you simplify it enough to reproduce in actual code? I don't know if I want the full UnitsConversion.h header, but I need it.

Comment: EUnits and EUnitConversion are still undefined. Try to make one code block that generates the error, please. [mcve] You can delete stuff. :)

Comment: @KennyOstrom Thanks for your reply!  I made a shortened example code, and along the way discovered some clues as to the cause of the error.

Comment: Is `PressureD` supposed to return an `int` or a `double`?

Comment: @o11c that was a mistake when I copied in the header.  I'm fixing it now... should be int

Comment: Probably unrelated, but the declspec (import vs export) is usually switched on a #define, and is generally import in the code that actually uses it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it!  The problem was the inclusion of `__stdcall` in the function declaration, or rather the omission of `__stdcall` in the function pointer type definition.  It seems like with certain combinations of architecture, the `__stdcall` may or may not cause a type conversion error if `__stdcall` is not also in the pointer type definition.  Declaring my function pointer type as follows:

```
typedef double(__stdcall *convertFunc)(EUnits, EUnits, double);
typedef int(__stdcall *convertFuncD)(EUnits, EUnits, double*,double*,int);
typedef int(__stdcall *convertFuncF)(EUnits, EUnits, float*, float*, int);
```

resolved the error!

Comment: Also, you get a more helpful error message if you create a PropertyMetaData instance. (without the template related errors from std::map)